# IF Statement in MySQL, using THEN and ELSE

Tags: php, mysql

I am testing out IF statements in MySQL for the first time and I am coming across an error.

I am trying to firstly, find out how many rows are in the table, then depending on whether the count is less than or equal to five, return all of the rows in the table, or if it isn't, return all posts in the range used within the LIMIT clause.

The error I am receiving is as follows;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Posts` <= 5 THEN SELECT * FROM `Posts`
>   ELSE SELECT * FR' at line 1

Please can you tell me where I am going wrong?

Max.

```
$query = mysql_query(
    "IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Posts` <= 5 
     THEN 
         SELECT * FROM `Posts` 
     ELSE 
         SELECT * FROM `Posts` LIMIT $from, $limit") 
     or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: AFAIK mysql IF works like this http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't simple If ELSE Statement work in mySql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294312/why-wont-simple-if-else-statement-work-in-mysql)

Comment: @dotoree there are two `IF` constructs in MySQL but `IF .. ELSE` cannot be used like this, see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/if-statement.html

Comment: @Kaii thanks for info I meant to say except stored procedures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you don't need to do this. Mysql handles this automatically, just use

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `Posts` LIMIT $from, $limit";
```

Comment: @Kaii, Actually, I dont think the above statement can be executed inside a mysql_query() at all. I want just fixing the error, that's all

Answer (score 3):

The [`IF .. THEN .. ELSE` syntax in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) is only available for procedural code (stored precudures, functions, triggers..), but not for `SELECT` statements.

Instead, the control flow functions [`IF()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) and the more verbose [`CASE WHEN .. THEN .. END`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) can be used in `SELECT` queries. But this is of no help in your case, when you actually want to execute two different queries depending on a condition.

In your special case i'm unsure if you even need to do that: when there are only five or less posts in the table, a `LIMIT 0,10` will give you those five posts without error:

```
$sql =  "SELECT * FROM Posts LIMIT $from, $limit";
```